# alphanumeric validation javascript without regex 2

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, arraylist

if i run, validation just can be work only on symbol "/", if I input the other symbol except / didnt working. I'm not use regex.

```
if(nama!==""){
    var i;
    var list = new Array ("/","!", "@", "#","$","%","%","^","&","*",
                          "(",")","_","+","=","-","`","~",";","<",
                          ">",".","?","[","]","{","}",",");

    var llength = list.length;
    for(i=0; i<llength; i++)
    {
        if(nama.match(list[i]))
        {
            alert("Full Name must not contain any number and symbol");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are killing the loop by using the `return` keyword in the `else` block, i,e. your loop iterates only once. You don't need an `else` block there. You should use the `return true` statement _after_ the loop.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be several problems here. One is that you are calling `return true` as soon as you reach a valid character. That means that you'll never check anything else if the first letter is valid.

Another problem is that you are trying to check for invalid characters, but how can you know you've checked them all?

A better approach to the whole problem might be to only a list of *valid* letters; The changes to your original could might be something like the following:

```
var list = new Array ("a", "A", "b", "B", ... [etc] );

for(i=0; i<llength; i++)
{
    if(!nama.match(list[i]))
    {
        alert("Full Name can only contain letters a-z!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

This should only quit the loop (and the containing function) when an invalid character is encountered.